# Lost in the indices!

Tags: geodesic, euler-lagrange-equation, index-notation

I'm trying to derive from the Lagrangian

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}g_{ij}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j,$$

the geodesic equations

$$\ddot{x}^k+\sum_{i,j}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_lg^{kl}\left(\frac{\partial g_{lj}}{\partial x^i}+\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j}-\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\right)\right)\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j=0.\tag{1}$$

So,

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^l}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j,$$

and

$$\begin{align*}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^l}&=
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\Big(g_{lj}\dot{x}^j+g_{il}\dot{x}^i\Big)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_k\left(g_{lk}\dot{x}^k+g_{kl}\dot{x}^k\right)\\
&=\sum_k g_{kl}\dot{x}^k,\end{align*}$$

since $g_{ij}=g_{ji}$. Then substituting these into the Euler-Lagrange equation gives (where a dot indicates a derivative with respect to $\tau$)

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^l}\right)
&=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^l}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\left(\sum_k g_{kl}\dot{x}^k\right)
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j.
\end{align*}$$

This is where my problems begin! Evaluating the derivative gives

$$
\sum_k\left(\frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k+g_{kl}\ddot{x}^k\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j
$$
**Now, was it appropriate here to take the partial derivative with respect to $x^i$ or could/should I have chosen another free index; i.e. $j$ or $l$? (I don't think that I can choose $l$ as that is being used in the metric - or can I?!)**

Moving along, I tried splitting up the LHS in a similar way to something I saw in another post:

$$
\sum_i \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^k}\dot{x}^k\dot{x}^i + \sum_k\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k+g_{kl}\ddot{x}^k\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j,
$$

and multiplying by the inverse metric gives

$$
\sum_i \frac{1}{2} g^{lk} \frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^k}\dot{x}^k\dot{x}^i + \sum_k\left(\frac{1}{2} g^{lk} \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k+g^{lk} g_{kl}\ddot{x}^k\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j} g^{lk} \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j.
$$

**I'm not sure how to proceed from here in order to obtain the form of $(1)$. Also, is this even correct?**

$$
\sum_k g^{lk} g_{kl}\ddot{x}^k
$$

I'm sure that I've read somewhere that you can't have the dummy index repeated more than twice in a term.

**Any help will be appreciated!**

Comment: Reading this question reminded me why [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in
$$\sum_k\left(\frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k+g_{kl}\ddot{x}^k\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j$$
you have missed a sum over $i$. It should be
$$\sum_k\left(\sum_i \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k+g_{kl}\ddot{x}^k\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j$$
i.e.
$$\sum_{i,k} \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k + \sum_k g_{kl}\ddot{x}^k = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j$$

Here, because of symmetry of $i$ and $k$ in $\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k$, the partial derivative of $g$ can be symmetrized:
$$
\sum_{i,k} \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k
= \frac12 \sum_{i,k} \left( \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i} + \frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^k} \right) \dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k
$$

Thus we have
$$
\frac12 \sum_{i,k} \left( \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i} + \frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^k} \right) \dot{x}^i\dot{x}^k
+ \sum_k g_{kl}\ddot{x}^k
= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}\,\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\sum_k g_{kl}\ddot{x}^k + \frac12 \sum_{i,j} \left( \frac{\partial g_{jl}}{\partial x^i} + \frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j} - \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l} \right) \dot x^i \dot x^j = 0
$$

Comment: Nicely explained.  Note that to obtain the equation at the top of the question, one would then have to multiply by $g^{lm}$, sum over $l$, and then use the fact that $\sum_l g^{lm} g_{kl} = \delta^m {}_k$.

Comment: Thank you. So, whenever a new term is introduced into a summation, we must remember to sum over its index.

Comment: It doesn't really have to do with the introduction of a new term. Remember how the term was introduced. You were using the chain rule on a function of several variables:
$$\frac{d}{d\tau} g_{kl} = \sum_i \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i} \frac{dx^i}{d\tau} = \sum_i \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i} \dot x^i.$$

Comment: Ah! of course, as in $$\frac{\mathrm{d}g_{kl}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=\frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^0}\frac{\mathrm{d}x^0}{\mathrm{d}\tau}+\frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x^1}{\mathrm{d}\tau}+\frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x^2}{\mathrm{d}\tau}+\frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^3}\frac{\mathrm{d}x^3}{\mathrm{d}\tau}.$$ The summations and indices make it easy to forget what you're actually dealing with!

Comment: Einstein got tired of writing sum signs and skipped them, at least when dealing with tensors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation